# How to combine Django and Node.Js as backend?

Tags: python, node.js, django, sockets

I am Python/Django developer, But, there are features in Node.Js which is very important for me to use.

Is it possible to be done on a single server? or do i have to use them separately to have no bugs?

Note: I have almost no knowledge about `Node.Js` just need it for a single task which i can understand, is it still required?

---

So for example, there is a Node.Js server which does specific task, It get's the information and sends to Django using to specific port AES 128 encrypted UDP socket, Python server's socket is bound to specific port, and will listen to it, when information is received, It will fill up specific model and continue listening to port.

Example in code:

Python ( Using socket library ):

```
import socket
from multiprocessing import process
import sys

IPv4 = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(8000)


class SendAndReceive():

    def Listen(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(2)
            self.data, self.addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
            if sys.getsizeof(data) > 23:
                self.model_will_be_filled = True
                self.Send()

    def Send(self):
        if self.model_will_be_filled = True:
            s.sendto(self.data, ("NodeJs server ip here", 8000))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main = SendAndReceive()
    Listening = Process(target=Main.Listen())
    Listening.start()
```

Is there any way doing it on one server? Or do i need to maximum knowledge of Node.Js basics and Socket.IO? Should i use redis/pika?

Comment: You can not use JavaScript library like socket.io in other language(Python, Java, PHP, C#, Ruby etc). You can use this library only in JavaScript environment like Node.JS, PhantomJS, etc.

Comment: you can have many programs using socket on one computer/server but they have to use different ports. Probably you already have many programs using socket with different ports - ie. ping, ftp server, ssh server, web server, database - so you can run Node.JS too (you can run even two Node.Js if you need it but every Node.Js has to use different port).

Comment: Thanks for the info, but i've heard once that it is possible to install some Node.Js features on Django. @furas Thanks a lot, also is there any instruction how can i do it?

Comment: I've never heard about it - but I think that to run some Node.Js features on Django you would need JavaScript intepreter in Python (and probably Node.Js writted in Python because mostly one features need other features which need another features [,etc.] which need Node.Js server). I would rather look for Python module with similar features.

Comment: I need to run specific library from Node.Js, it's not official and requires manual installing from github. I also could find library in Python that uses redis and pika with similar features, but it was not official and hardly understandable.